# Maximum number of intervals that are not a subset of another interval (Partitions)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let's say I have a multidimensional interval $I$, which is partitioned into a finite collection $\Gamma=\{I_k\}_{k=1}^N$ of nonoverlapping intervals.

Define the norm $|\Gamma|=\max_k(diam(I_k))$.

For another partition $P=\{J_k\}$ with $|P|<\delta$ ($\delta$ to be chosen by us), do we have a condition on the maximum volume of all the intervals $J_k$ which are **not a subset** of any $I_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq N$?

What $\delta$ do we choose?

I recall that there is such a maximum volume provided we choose a certain $\delta$, but I forgot the details..

Thanks for any help. (I need this number for part of a proof)

Comment: Not quite sure of what you mean by a multi-dimensional interval. Is it a union of intervals having disjoint closures ?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh It is a Cartesian product of closed intervals, eg [0,1]x[0,1].

Comment: So the $J_k$'s that are not subsets must intersect the boundary of an $I_j$ so the volume is bounded by that of a $\delta$ ngbh of the (interior) surfaces of the $I_j$'s. But not sure how in what way you want to describe the max volume?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh That's right. I realized there is no maximum number of such $J_k$, so wondering if there is a maximum total volume of all the $J_k$. An upper bound (in terms of delta) will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a crude (but simple) estimate. Each of the $J_k$'s in question must intersect the boundary of some $I_j$ so the total volume is bounded by the volume of the $\delta$-neighborhood of the surfaces of the $I_j$'s. In dimension $d$ this volume is bounded by 
$$  N \; (2 \;  \delta) \;  [2d \; (|\Gamma|+2\delta)^{d-1}] $$

Comment: Nice. May I ask how did you arrive at the last expression?

Comment: What I can understand is the $d$-dimensional cube has $2d$ faces, which explains the $2d$. I am a little confused by the rest.

Comment: $|\Gamma|+2\delta$ is a (very) crude bound for  the lengths of the sides making up each surface. Power $d-1$ to get the surface 'area' and $2\delta$ to get the volume.